# Swift 4, UIStackViews Not Displaying

Tags: swift

Strange bug(s) I'm encountering..

This code:

```
    // Label 1
    let textLabel1 = UILabel()
    textLabel1.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
    textLabel1.text  = "Label1"
    textLabel1.textAlignment = .center

    // Label 2
    let textLabel2 = UILabel()
    textLabel2.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    textLabel2.text  = "Label2"
    textLabel2.textAlignment = .center

    // Label 3
    let textLabel3 = UILabel()
    textLabel3.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    textLabel3.text  = "Label3"
    textLabel3.textAlignment = .center


    let h1StackView = UIStackView()
    h1StackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    h1StackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    h1StackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    h1StackView.spacing = 0
    h1StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel3)
    h1StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel2)
    self.view.addSubview(h1StackView)

    let h2StackView = UIStackView()
    h2StackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    h2StackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    h2StackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    h2StackView.spacing = 0
    h2StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel3)
    h2StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel1)
    self.view.addSubview(h2StackView)


    //Stack View
    let stackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: pos.VERT_STACK_Y, width: pos.SCREEN_WIDTH, height: pos.VERT_STACK_HEIGHT))
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.vertical
    stackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    stackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    stackView.spacing = 0
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(h1StackView)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(h2StackView)
    self.view.addSubview(stackView)
```

Gives this view:
[Buggy Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4ODn.png)
[image: Buggy Image 1]

This is close to correct, but wrong because I'm not expecting that big blue bar, rather, half blue - half green.

It gets a little weirder though for me...

If I change just one character in the code (textLabel2 to textLabel1):

(This):

```
    let h1StackView = UIStackView()
    h1StackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    h1StackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    h1StackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    h1StackView.spacing = 0
    h1StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel3)
    h1StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel2)
    self.view.addSubview(h1StackView)
```

(To this):

```
    let h1StackView = UIStackView()
    h1StackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxis.horizontal
    h1StackView.distribution = .fillEqually
    h1StackView.alignment = UIStackViewAlignment.fill
    h1StackView.spacing = 0
    h1StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel3)
    h1StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel1)
    self.view.addSubview(h1StackView)
```

Then I get this view:

[Buggy Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHNqs.png)
[image: Buggy Image 2]

It seems there are two problems and I can't quite fix either.. any ideas? I'm hoping this is a me problem and not a Swift/Xcode one.

(P.S. Sorry not enough rep to embed images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem resides in the logic of that **single instance can only be inside one view at a time** , so first when you repeated adding lbl3  to both the horizontal stackViews , it appeared at the last one (stack2) , same when you repeated adding 1,3  , they only show inside horizontal stack 2 , so to repeat you have to create another object , also if you decided to create a main stack to hold the 2 horizontal stacks then comment these 2 lines

```
self.view.addSubview(h1StackView)
self.view.addSubview(h2StackView)
```

Answer (score 0):

`arrangedSubViews` is a subset of all `subviews` —

From the docs on [`UIView`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview)

> A parent view may contain any number of subviews but each subview has only one superview.

This is expanded on in [addSubView(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622616-addsubview)

> Views can have only one superview. If view already has a superview and that view is not the receiver, this method removes the previous superview before making the receiver its new superview.

So when you add `textLabel3` to `h2StackView` in this line:

```
h2StackView.addArrangedSubview(textLabel3)
```

You're implicitly removing it from `h1StackView`